# Using CSS and JQuery to display total count of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS, JQuery, and just started to build my first site.

I have a counter that counts the number of items in a list. The end result I'm working towards is to turn it into a notification badge/label and display it to the the user. It's functionality is exactly like the notification badges you get for your apps in iOS.

The counter works fine and it displays the correct total of the list items the only problem is displaying it in the appropriate location. I want to display it right beside "Recent Updates" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDToz.jpg)), it currently only works when displayed at the end of the list - this makes sense since the code is read sequentially.

I looked at possibilities such as `li:nth-last-child(1)` but I don't know how to extract the counter value, every example I've seen uses it to highlight the element by changing the background color.

This bring me to the question, would it possible to take the result of the counter value form CSS, store it a JS variable and then place it wherever I want within the body of the HTML doc?

If it's possible, how would I be able to do this? 
If not, what are my options?

**CODE**:

```css
ul {
  counter-reset: item;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: item;
}
.count:after {
  display: block;
  content: counter(item);
}
```

```html
<div class="row item desktop description">
  <h3 class="margin-pull title-padding description">Recent Updates</h3><span class="label label-danger label-as-badge" style="font-size: 1em">15</span>
</div>
<div class="row scrollable kinetic margin-push-micro text-left count">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - ONE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - TWO</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - THREE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FOUR</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FIVE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - SIX</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - SEVEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - EIGHT</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - NINE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - TEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - ELEVEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - TWELVE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - THIRTEEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FOURTEEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - FIFTEEN</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use CSS for this at all. jQuery exposes the number of elements within a collection through its `length` property, so to count the number of list items all you have to do is:

```
var count = $('ul.list-unstyled').children().length;
```

---

#### Demo

```js
var count = $('ul.list-unstyled').children().length;

$('#result').text(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row scrollable kinetic margin-push-micro text-left count">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - ONE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - TWO</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - THREE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FOUR</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FIVE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - SIX</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - SEVEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - EIGHT</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - NINE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - TEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - ELEVEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - TWELVE</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - THIRTEEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>04.15.2015</strong> - FOURTEEN</li>
    <li class="space"><strong>01.24.2015</strong> - FIFTEEN</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for the past 8hrs, the solution is so simple, thank you so much James!

Answer (score 0):

By using jquery to just count items in your Ul you can do it this way.

```
   var count = $(".list-unstyled li").length;
    $('#count').html(count);
```

Look at js fiddle.. now you can put that span where ever you want.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/82gkygmd/)

Answer (score 0):

you can just wait till the dom is loaded and run the script then...

```
$(function(){
  $(".label-as-badge").html($(".space").length);  
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mv5vo4e4/